# Tax calculation on custom pricing

Tags: magento

If I create a new order in the admin, add the product and then select the "custom price" box to change the price the calculations go wrong. The row subtotal has the wrong amount in it and as a result the tax and total are wrong as well.

Though the subtotal at the bottom of the page is displayed correct i.e. with the new custom price, the tax is calculated on the original price.

e.g. original price for a product is Rs.1000 and tax is at 5%, the final price should be Rs.1050/-. After clicking on the custom price option, if I change the price to Rs.900/- the tax is still calculated as 5% of Rs.1000 i.e. Rs.50 instead of Rs.45/- i.e. tax at 5% on Rs.900/-.

So after custom price is applied the total payable amount should be reflecting as Rs.900 + Rs.45(@5%tax) = Rs.945 instead of Rs.900 + Rs.50 = Rs.950

I have my site set for pricing excluding tax.

Comment: Adding code would improve chances of successful troubleshooting :)

Answer (score 1):

Set 'Tax Calculation Method Based On' to 'Unit Price'.